Blazor Components (CascadingValue / DiagramCanvas) are not getting redrawn on change
I am pretty new to Blazor sorry if the question is not very appropriate, but I really tried a lot of the stuff out there.
<RadzenCard Visible="Visible">
    <div>@Cntxt.Values.FirstOrDefault().BatchId</div>
<div class="diagram-container">
        <CascadingValue Value="@Diagram">
        <DiagramCanvas ></DiagramCanvas>
    </CascadingValue>
</div>
</RadzenCard>

This is the Component that I would like to re-render, is there anything specific about CascadingValue or DiagramCanvas that these elements cannot be re-rendered?
I am using BlazorDiagrams and I want to perform re-render of the component.
However doesn't matter if I call StateHasChanged(), change properties etc.. it never does re-render the component.
None of the stuff proposed in Blazor docs are working for me
